# Не работает событие checked = false javascript

Tags: javascript

В теории данный код должен работать, но не тут то было...

```
<input type="radio" value="1">
<input type="button" value="strat" id="btn">
```

Javascript код

```
btn.onclick = function(){
    var delet = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
    for(var i = 0; i < delet.length; i++){
        delet.checked = false;
    }
    if(delet.checked = false){
        alert("true");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("false");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны обращаться к элементу списка `delet` внутри цикла, а не к самому списку `delet`.

```
btn.onclick = function(){
    var delet = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
    for(var i = 0; i < delet.length; i++){
        delet[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```